# AIR application Mouse.hide() not working

Tags: air, mouse

I created a fullscreen app with the following to hide the mouse...

```
// need this hack to hide the mouse for AIR for some reason...for OSX
// http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/11/16/air-hiding-the-mouse/
stage.nativeWindow.activate();
stage.nativeWindow.orderToBack();
stage.nativeWindow.orderToFront();              
Mouse.hide();
```

This works on my machine at home running OSX Lion...but when this is installed on the client's machine (also running OSX...I need to find out the version), the mouse does not hide?

When I take out the 3 line hack before the Mouse.hide(), the mouse does not hide on my machine. Will test this out on the client's machine too.

Anyone experience this before?

Answer (score 1):

Are you including `flash.ui.Mouse` in your code?

```
import flash.ui.Mouse;
```

Take a look in this site: http://samhassan.co.uk/2008/10/08/air-10-mousehide-work-around/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hide mouse cursor when the first enterFrame event is fired. Some elements are not fully available till the first frame is build:

```
// i.e. on main app initilize event handler
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    Mouse.hide();
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
}
```

This way, you have not to rely on hacks or workarounds.